# Creating elements slightly offset from the last, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, increment

I have a canvas called "workArea" that is much bigger than the viewport and draggable.  I don't think that's relevant, but throwing it out there.  I'm dynamically creating elements with knockout using the init function below.  It should create each consecutive element 25 pixels to the right and down from the last one (technically the selected one, but the last created one gets selected automatically).  The locy variable seems to be set and incrimenting as expected, via 25, but the locx variable gets exponentially larger each time.  I must be missing something stupid.

Javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Item = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var locx;
    var locy;
    var $pos = $('.itemView.focused').position();
    var $work = $('#workArea');
    if ($('.itemView.focused').length > 0) {
        locx = $pos.left;
        locy = $pos.top;
        console.log('focused element "' + $('.itemView.focused').attr('name') + '" is at ' + locx + ',' + locy)
    } else {
        locx = $work.width() / 2;
        locy = $work.height() / 2;
        console.log('No focused elements, creating at ' + locx + ',' + locy)
    }
    $element.draggable({ ...draggable options here...});
    locx += 25;
    locy += 25;
    $element.css('left', locx.toString() + 'px').css('top', locy.toString() + 'px');
    console.log('Created new element at ' + locx + ',' + locy)
    }
};
```

And here is the console log, which matches where they are showing up on the UI

```
No focused elements, creating at 2000,1000
Created new element at 2025,1025
focused element "SERVER01" is at 2025,1025
Created new element at 2050,1050
focused element "SERVER02" is at 2298,1050
Created new element at 2323,1075
focused element "SERVER03" is at 2819,1075
Created new element at 2844,1100
focused element "APP01" is at 3588,1100
Created new element at 3613,1125
```

Comment: Try using `$pos = $('.itemView.focused').position()` and `$work = $('#workArea')`: does that change anything?

Comment: updated code to reflect that change just in case

Comment: I adjusted the size of the workArea so that it is evenly divisible by 2.  No more decimals, just in case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... had a rogue "float: left" style applied on a CSS class I forgot about.

It's working perfectly now.

I would vote to close for "too localized" but this seems like pretty odd behavior so maybe it can help someone?  I won't be offended if someone does vote to close.